# R: Shiny input container resizing for checkboxGroupInput

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'm building a shiny app with multiple user inputs. One of these inputs is a `checkboxGroupInput()`, with `inline=TRUE`. However, given that there are 5 checkboxes, the boxes flow over to the next line. I have tried to resize the text and boxes, however all other aspects / margins do not scale accordingly (obviously).
Hence, best would be to rescale the whole container. Understand that the class of the container is:

```
class = form-group shiny-input-container.
```

Unclear though as how to resize the container for the `checkBoxes` specifically. Here is the code for the `checkboxGroupInput`:

```
 checkboxGroupInput('EQUITY_show_vars', 
 'Equity:',
  ETF_Names[1:5], 
  selected =       ETF_Names[1:4],inline=TRUE),
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `checkboxGroupInput()` contained in? It looks fine, obviously, if I put just that in the page. Is it in a `sidebarPanel`? Or what?

Comment: Yes, it sits within a sidebarPanel